# ExecJs, coffeescript and JS runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ExecJs : It is used to run js code directly in ruby and result will be ruby object..

Coffeescript: it is language as js that having less code and nice performance over js.

Rubyracer: It evaluate js from ruby.

But I dont have a clear picture how all three are related and their work flow..